# ConcurrentModification exception in honeycomb

Tags: android, google-maps, android-3.0-honeycomb, concurrentmodification

I'm getting this error while working on map (Drawing line on map using GetDirection API).
I have used CopyOnWriteArrayList still it sometimes throws ConcurrentModification exception.

```
CopyOnWriteArrayList<GeoPoint> pointArray;
pointArray =  parcer.getDirectionParcer(jsonObject);

GeoPoint gp1;
GeoPoint gp2 = src;
Iterator<GeoPoint> it1 = pointArray.iterator();

//for(int i=0;i<pointArray.size();i++) // the last one would be crash

Utility.debugger("2");
while (it1.hasNext()) {
    try {
        gp1 = gp2;
        gp2 = (GeoPoint) it1.next();
        mMapView.getOverlays().add(new MyOverLay(gp1,gp2,2,color));
    } catch (ConcurrentModificationException e) {
        Utility.debugger("exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

It gives error in `it1.next()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling this code in a non UI thread?

The `ConcurrentModificationException` may be due to adding overlays in an Non UI thread, while the UI thread is trying to access the overlays.  You can only modify overlays on the UI thread.